# How to load API's in WordPress?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, api

I am trying to learn WP Theme development. And I am wondering what's the proper way to load api's? For example Google Maps:

`<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

Should I enqueue the API url, or how should I do? I am a bit confused since this api for example reffers to a /js folder and not a direct script?

Comment: have you tried enqueueing it?

Comment: I have'nt tried. I got in in my head tag right now. But I would like to know what the "proper" way is when it comes to API's  :)

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For google maps in a template file, I just do this:

```
wp_register_script( 'google-maps-api', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js' );
wp_print_scripts( 'google-maps-api' );
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd have to do that in the template when you can just enqueue to output in `wp_footer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can enqueue it like any other script. If it resolves, it resolves, if it doesn't, it doesn't. The contents of the URL matter none to the enqueue function.